# What happens when you pass a signed integer to a function that expects an unsigned integer for the purpose of filtering/mixing?

Tags: c++, c, unsigned-integer

I need to resize some images and the library I'm using is **stb**, the free header-only C library, and it has functions for `uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, and `float`. I have some images that are signed int16, with values ranging from negative to positive. What would happen to those values if I pass those signed ints cast as unsigned int, either explicitly or implicitly by the compiler? I'm guessing it would completely break. Do I have to therefore create a new buffer, convert them to `float`, and call the `float` function, then convert those `float` values back to `int16`? Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "signed int 16"? If each color channel's value range from -32768 to 32767, while the image library interprets a pair of suffering bytes as values from 0-65535, then it seems obvious to me that the straightforward conversion would be to add 32768 to each value, which reduces to simply flipping each value's high bit. Did you try doing that?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik And then subtract 32768 from the value? Either way I need to fill another buffer, don't I?

Comment: Whether or not you need to copy buffers depends on your use case. Presumably, you're passing an input image buffer to the relevant resize function, which returns a pointer to a new buffer. Flipping the top bits in those *actual* buffers would work, if you don't need them "as-is" for anything else. (And flipping again will also do the 32768 subtraction.)

Comment: Depending on the actual resize algorithm it might even work if you pass it as is. If it is nearest neighbor or similar, where no mathematical operation is done on the color values themselves (unlike bilinear interpolation or averaging of kinds).

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You mention casting the values, but also using the existing buffer which suggests that you actually contemplate casting pointers to the values.  These are different operations.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well I pass the function a pointer to the values. Eventually the function will read those values as an unsigned integer.

Comment: I think some information on the resize function you're using would be helpful (or even a link to docs); also, maybe a short code snippet that shows us how you intend to use the resized buffer, and whether you're happy to 'discard' the original.

Comment: Whether or not you need to copy the input values depends on whether the original input buffer is modifiable, and whether you need to keep the original values. If the original input buffer is modifiable and you no longer need the original values, you could modify the contents of the original input buffer in-place to save memory. If you do need the original values from the input buffer, and it is modifiable, you could undo the modification to the input buffer contents in-place if you are short of memory. If memory availability is not a problem, it would be more efficient to work on a copy.

Comment: If converting to float and back again, you may still need to apply some linear transformation to the input and output values, depending on the range of values the function expects. For example, if it expects values in the range 0.0 to 1.0, you would need to apply an offset and a scaling factor to your 16-bit signed integer values.

Comment: Could you illustrate the issue with a code example?

Comment: Try this site: https://cppinsights.io/ it helps to reveal all implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an array of `int16_t` to a function that expects an array of `uint16_t`, using a `(uint16_t *)` cast to silence the compiler warning, whether the code will execute or *break* depends on how it handles values in the range 32768 to 65535.  Any negative entries in the array will be read as large positive values offset by 65536, so with a strong discontinuity at `0`.

Depending of the actual algorithm implemented in the *filter*, the effect will range from *normal* to *unexpected* and including *surprising*, *weird*, *psychedelic* and the like.

Comment: To be even more explicit, if you are processing (for example) image data from a 12-bit camera, so that you know the data is bounded 0-4095, then you can freely pass your int16_t data to the uint16_t function with a pointer typecast.  The values in the buffer interpreted as uint16_t will be numerically the same as interpreted as int16_t.

Comment: @Peter How will a *signed* integer value of (say) -2 be numerically the same when interpreted as an *unsigned* value?

Comment: Of course a -2 would be interpreted as something wildly different and incorrect.  I said "strictly positive data".  But also the answer above expresses this better than I did.  It /may/ work if your data is strictly positive, and if the /filter/ meets certain criteria.  I withdraw my advice above.  Do it right to avoid problems later.

Answer (score 0):

Two things shall be taken into considerations:

1. is there a communication between different devices? such as driver etc... then endianness shall be checked or even two unsigned bytes values will differ from architecture to another,
2. When using a signed integer, first bit is always considered as integer sign, therefore you will be following a 2s complement representation, and the max of 2 Bytes will be 2^15 - 1 instead of 2^16 - 1 with a signing capability

therefore:

- in an uint16_t the range is from 0 ... 65535
- while in a int16_t the range is from -32768 ... 32767